# Stash Embed Variable Assignment

Tags: stash, embeds

I have two Stash embeds. Both embed templates accept a `color` variable, but it's optional:

```
{if '{stash:color}'}
  {stash:color}<br>
{/if}
```

If I explicitly set the variable in both embeds, everything works as expected:

```
{exp:stash:embed name='template1' stash:color='Red'}
{exp:stash:embed name='template2' stash:color='Green'}
```

Outputs:

```
Red
Green
```

If I set the variable in the first embed but not the second, it also works as expected:

```
{exp:stash:embed name='template1' stash:color='Red'}
{exp:stash:embed name='template2'}
```

Outputs:

```
Red
```

But if I leave the first variable empty and set the second, both are assigned the second value:

```
{exp:stash:embed name='template1'}
{exp:stash:embed name='template2' stash:color='Green'}
```

Outputs:

```
Green
Green
```

Is this a bug? Shouldn't Stash embed variables only be scoped to the embed template they're passed to?

- Stash 2.6.0
- EE 2.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash embed variables are available *anywhere* in the template that is parsed later in the parse order, i.e. they create a variable with global scope. This is by design - so that, for example, child embeds inherit variables passed to their parent, and so that the embeds can pass information to siblings. I would argue this is a feature rather than a bug, but I understand why you may disagree.

When using multiple instances of the same embed that accepts variables, you should set each variable explicitly:

```
{exp:stash:embed name='template1' stash:color=''}
{exp:stash:embed name='template2' stash:color='Green'}
```

Comment: If that's the case, then what's the difference between `{exp:stash:embed name='template1' stash:color='Red'}` and `{exp:stash:color}Red{/exp:stash:color}{exp:stash:embed name='template1'}`?

Comment: The difference is that embed variable values are assigned at the exact point the embed is parsed, which by default is at the end of template parsing (`process="end"` - but could be at the start, before the template is parsed if `process="start"`). So explicitly setting embed variables ensures that the resulting Stash variables have the desired value at the point the embed is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to include the `file_name` in your embed code.

The docs refer to the same template but it's likely that what you're seeing may be related.

Give it a shot and see what happens.

PS. How are you setting your stash var if they're both named the same ?